# firebase Storage sync

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the image_list in Uri format.
In the process of retrieving photos from firebase storage, a coroutine was used to solve the async.

```
private fun test()  {

    val storageReference =
            FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Ballad_images")
    val temp_time = ArrayList<String>()
    val temp_time_3 = ArrayList<String>()
    val image_list = ArrayList<String>()

    
    storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
        GlobalScope.launch() {

            val job1 = launch {
                for (fileRef in listResult.items) {
                    fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { Uri ->

                        image_list.add(Uri.toString())
                        image_list.sort()
                    }

                }
            }

            val job2 = launch {
                for (fileRef in listResult.items) {
                    temp_time.add(fileRef.name)

                }//for
                for (i in 0..temp_time.size - 1) {
                    var temp_time_2 = temp_time.get(i).split('.')//2021 05 29 -1 jpg
                    temp_time_3.add(temp_time_2[1])
                    //05

                }//for
            }


            runBlocking {
                job1.join()
                println("image_list : " + image_list.size)
                job2.join()
                println("temp_time : " + temp_time_3)
                //delay(4000L)
                println("image_list : " + image_list.size)


            }
        }//GlobalScope

    }
}
```

end job1.join()
After finishing job2.join()
If you give it a delay, the data will come out.

When I see it, in join1
I think this is happening because of fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener

Is there a way to populate the image_list from job1?

Comment: Have you tried to use one job inside another?

Comment: It comes out well no matter what operation you put above or below the for statement